# Redirect from non-existing route in node?

Tags: javascript, node.js

In my app, if I try to enter some non-existing route, lets say - `www.mydomain.com/nonExistingRoute` Im getting a blank page with text: `Cannot GET /nonExistingRoute/`.

What's more - if I do it locally (when running app in development mode, on localhost) if I do the same, it enters correctly `/` route (coz ive set it in client side routing). But it doesnt work properly in production mode (on my domain).

My app config in `app.js` in node:

```
app.use('/api', apiRouter);  // only api responds
app.use('*', express.static('public'));  // serving static files
```

**Note**: I have server-side rendering active. So every route, like `/` is pre-rendered on server side.

What can I do that if someone gets non existing route (but without `/api`), he gets redirected to `/`?
Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just add this as the last rule:

```
  app.use((_, res) => res.redirect("/"));
```